# Specify valid wake lock level for ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

I'm trying to wake device from a thread with the following code :

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) GydeApplication.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,
        "MyWakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire(10*60*1000L /*10 minutes*/);
```

And added the following permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

But get the following error :

```
Must specify a valid wake lock level.
```

On `wakelock` creation.

Answer (score 0):

```
FULL_WAKE_LOCK
PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK
SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK
SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK
```

**You need to specify one of**

Answer (score 0):

In addition to SahdevRajput74's answer:
`FULL_WAKE_LOCK`is deprecated as of API level 17.
Use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`insteadas suggested in [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#FULL_WAKE_LOCK).